# Create/Delete files on Timings

Tags: c#, file-io, timer

I am connected to an OpenVPN server. For connecting I need 2 files (username/passowrd & other) that I create and delete programmatically. On successful connection I delete those files as strictly don't want to keep such files on PC.

The problem is : almost every hr the server needs those files again and if it can't find it gets disconnected. So the user got to connect again. This is a sort of problem for the user.

I was thinking, if I can create those 2 files every 55 mins & delete after 10 mins. With this, after 59mins the server will find the file and stay alive and again after 10mins I delete those files.

Can anyone tell/guide me how do I create/delete files on certain timings. How to implemetn the timer feature. AND importantly, is this feature proper - I mean can this work out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use preshared key file authentication.
Use X509 (SSL certificate) authentication, and protect your private key with a password.
Don't delete or create any file, it doesn't make sense.

For more informations: http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html

Comment: I use SSL certificate only. But I delete the ovpn & username/password files (--enable-password). Even if I don't delete both the files, I still get disconnected after 1hr. ????

Comment: @Tvd. What's into the log (client and server)?